# Windows 10 "Reset this PC" not available/missing

Tags: windows-10, reset

I have a Windows 10 Pro PC which I want to reset. A typical [guide](http://tunecomp.net/how-to-reset-windows-10/) says to use "**Settings** > **Update & security** > **Recovery** > **Reset this PC** section > **Get Started** button." I have the latest version of Windows 10, but I can't find this option, even when I search settings for "reset".

Instead, all I have is **More recovery options** > "Learn how to start afresh with a clean installation of Windows." This is a website link to [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10startfresh) where you have to download a tool (and the latest OS - roughly 3GB).

I tried to find "Reset this PC" on another Windows 10 PC (Home Premium) and another Win 10 Pro PC, and I can't find it on those either. All these PC's upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8 or 7.

I have two simple related questions.

1. Is this normal (post-Dec 2016) for upgraded Windows 10 that the "Reset this PC" is missing?
2. Is there any way to enable the "Reset this PC" option, or will I have to use a DVD disk or USB for a reset/refresh operation?

Comment: It is not normal and you will need a disk to perform the operation,I suggest using the option that is working for you, that requires downloading the tool.

Comment: this happend in win8 when you modified UAC. settings. restore the UAC settings to the default values.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't this happen when the recovery partition(s?) doesn't exist? Can you please edit your question with a screenshot of the Windows Disk Management program on your system?

Answer (score -1):

It looks very strange. Please press "winver" in search box and check the exact Windows version of your computer. If it is not the latest Windows 10 version 1709. Please try to update through Settings\Update & Security\Windows update.
If the issue persists, please try to Start Windows 10 and on the login screen, click on the Power button. Hold down the Shift key and click restart.Make sure you hold the Shift key down when Windows is restarting and don’t release it until you see the first screen with the troubleshoot option. Click Troubleshoot.Then you will see reset this PC